# DVB live streaming to android without encoding

Tags: android, vlc, video-encoding, live-streaming, dvb

I'm using mumudvb/dvblast or dvbviewer (all are for sending DVB-T videos over IP) for live streaming the TV channels through my local network.

vlc can play rtp or udp or http output and every thing is ok.

Video codec: h264

Audio codec: AAC

I'm using vlc to save every 10 seconds live content coming from mumudvb/dvbviewer/dvblast streaming (as chunked TS files) and make HLS and m3u8 index for apple and android devices. without any transcoding. And every thing is ok and both devices can play perfectly.

I mean that clients(android tv box) supports all encapsulation and video and audio codec of this content.

But when I play dvb to ip output as live streaming directly to android device via rtsp, udp or rtp (multicast or unicast) there are many problems.

"video without audio, audio without video, lack, latency, many errors from media player or videoview, app not responding, can't play this video and ..." each time.

I tried to live transcoding to low bit rate using vlc or ffmpeg and the problem is solved and can send and play via rtsp, rtp, udp or http.

**but the questions are:**

**1. If my device can play saved TS file over http (HLS or progressively)
    so why can't play live streams with same codec and content?**

**2. Can I encode all channels (14 video channels) multicast and coming
    from mumudvb/dvblast altogether without high CPU usage?**

**3. Is there any simple way and stable server to send DVB channels to
    Android directly without transcoding, proxing or ...  (udp and
    multicast is preferred)? just need a cheap way.**

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question. Try http://android.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @CommonsWare : May be I should change mediaplayer or videoview methods to play live streaming in my code.

Comment: None of your questions have anything to do with `MediaPlayer` or `VideoView`. If your objective is to get answers to your questions, please ask them in a more appropriate forum.

Comment: Do you answer for your solution Mohsen?

Answer (score 1):

1. Because the (part of the) software that's demuxing the network stream does not necessarily handle the same format that the (part of the) software that deals with files.
2. This is not a question you can answer without knowing how much is "high". In all cases, if you transcode, it'll take CPU and (hopefully) GPU/Video hardware resources that you don't take when just streaming back unmodified content.
3. Have a look at Kodi (on Android) and http://tvheadend.org
   Depending on your hardware, it might give you immediate solution if it works.

Else, if you have ~100$, you can buy a DVB-T2 network streaming device that comes with their own Android's software stack (and, as such, just work). I'm not sure stackoverflow is the right place for advertisement, and your question is not really linked with the theme of this site.